# How to display a Python namedtuple with a custom name inside a Pandas DataFrame cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have Python namedtuples for ICD codes. For example:

```
g40 = ICD(child=['G40.0', 'G40.1'], parent='G40-G47',
          code='G40', exclusion=['seizure (convulsive) NOS'],
          title='Epilepsy')
```

I would like to have a large number of such namedtuples stored in a Pandas DataFrame column. Each instance of the namedtuple has its own name.

I would like **only** the namedtuple's instance name or some other custom name to be displayed in the Pandas DataFrame cells as such:

```
   | icd         |  another_column
 ------------------------------------
 0 | g40         |  some other data
 1 | g41         |  more data
```

Then to access the underlying namedtuple data:

```
>>>df.icd[0].title

'Epilepsy'
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

ADDENDUM: Sample code instantiating some namedtuples.

```
# Example code

from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

ICD = namedtuple('ICD', ['inclusion', 'code', 'classKind', 'parent', 'title'])

g400 = ICD(inclusion=['Benign childhood epilepsy with centrotemporal EEG spikes', 'Childhood epilepsy with occipital EEG paroxysms'],
    code='G40.0',
    classKind='category',
    parent='G40',
    title='Localization-related (focal)(partial) idiopathic epilepsy and epileptic syndromes with seizures of localized onset')

g401 = ICD(inclusion=['Attacks without alteration of consciousness', 'Simple partial seizures developing into secondarily generalized seizures'],
    code='G40.1',
    classKind='category',
    parent='G40',
    title='Localization-related (focal)(partial) symptomatic epilepsy and epileptic syndromes with simple partial seizures')

g402 = ICD(inclusion=['Attacks with alteration of consciousness, often with automatisms', 'Complex partial seizures developing into secondarily generalized seizures'],
    code='G40.2',
    classKind='category',
    parent='G40',
    title='Localization-related (focal)(partial) symptomatic epilepsy and epileptic syndromes with complex partial seizures')

g403 = ICD(inclusion=['Benign: myoclonic epilepsy in infancy', 'Benign: neonatal convulsions (familial)',
               'Childhood absence epilepsy [pyknolepsy]', 'Epilepsy with grand mal seizures on awakening',
               'Juvenile: absence epilepsy', 'Juvenile: myoclonic epilepsy [impulsive petit mal]',
               'Nonspecific epileptic seizures: atonic', 'Nonspecific epileptic seizures: clonic',
               'Nonspecific epileptic seizures: myoclonic', 'Nonspecific epileptic seizures: tonic',
               'Nonspecific epileptic seizures: tonic-clonic'],
    code='G40.3',
    classKind='category',
    parent='G40',
    title='Generalized idiopathic epilepsy and epileptic syndromes')


df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'icd':[g400, g401, g402, g403], 'another_column':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
```

Comment: could you provide a sample code creating some named tuple and instances .

Comment: hi @sammywemmy. see addendum above for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed that was giving me some issues is the commas between the instances. They have no place there, so I removed them.

I used the `._asdict()` method for named tuples to get the dictionary format, and pass the result into a dataframe.

```
colln = [i._asdict() for i in (g400,g401,g402,g403)]

pd.DataFrame(colln).assign(another_column=['A','B','C','D'])

inclusion   code    classKind   parent  title   another_column
0   [Benign childhood epilepsy with centrotemporal...   G40.0   category     
    G40 Localization-related (focal)(partial) idiopath...   A
1   [Attacks without alteration of consciousness, ...   G40.1   category     
    G40 Localization-related (focal)(partial) symptoma...   B
2   [Attacks with alteration of consciousness, oft...   G40.2   category     
    G40 Localization-related (focal)(partial) symptoma...   C
3   [Benign: myoclonic epilepsy in infancy, Benign...   G40.3   category     
    G40 Generalized idiopathic epilepsy and epileptic ...   D
```

Note that you can't index using the tuple methods when in a dataframe; your best bet is to do everything you want outside the dataframe.

Comment: those are nice optimizations @sammywemmy, thanks. do you know why it is not posible to use the tuple methods from inside the dataframe? I was thinking along the lines of a Pandas extension (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html).

Comment: also my original question is if it is possible to display custom name inside the DataFrame as an "alias" to the namedtuple, see the text table in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: What I want to do is akin to how Pandas displays dates and timestamps in a DataFrame. It displays like a readable datetime but retains the datetime object under the hood.

Comment: not sure that is possible. Others might pitch in though.